# How can I add a new tab in product page in magento

Tags: magento, tabs, product

The default tabs in my product page are `Product Description`, `Reviews` and `Tags` (which was changed for testing purposes to -> **Hello there**). So I've managed to change the default name of one of the tabs, but i don't seem to remember where I made the change. Also I think there could be a more "Cleaner" way to achieve the same.

Regardless of the way to achieve it, I'd like to know how to add a new custom tab with custom product attributes to it.

You can find my sample product page [here.](http://www.train2brain.co.uk/index.php/certifications/ecdl-and-project-management/ecdl-certification/ecdl-7-units.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example if you want  to add tabs that will give you main description, a secondary description and then another tab that will have specific vehicle fitment data.

it's pretty easy. First of all you need to create phtml file for your new tab. Let it be info.phtml. Then add tab init section to xml file (as described in the article):

```
<action method="addTab" module="catalog" translate="title">
    <alias>info</alias>
    <title>Info</title>
    <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
    <template>catalog/product/view/info.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Inside of the phtml file you need to call:

```
<?php $product = $this->getProduct() ?>
```

Now you are able to output any product's attribute in this file:
Description:

```
<?php echo $product->getDescription() ?>
```

Special Price:

```
<?php echo $product->getSpecialPrice() ?>
```

if you want to read in detail you can go throw [link](http://www.woolleydesign.net/2012/07/magento-adding-tabs-to-your-product-pages/)

Comment: OK, but what happens if the attribute will be empty - empty. Tabs will occur anyway.

Comment: yes it will display as empty tab but you can also set some message at empty current tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation about how to create additional tabs on product page : http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-tabs-on-the-product-page/

To rename something on frontend, the easiest way is to set "Enabled for Frontend" in "System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Translate inline" to "yes" and then go to frontend and translate whatever you want, including tab names.

PS: translate inline doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

you can check your app\design\frontend[your project]\default\layout\catalog.xml

in magento 1.9 you can see the xml like this

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
            </block>
```

and you can add another like this

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.new.tab" as="new.tab" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>New Tab</value></action>
            </block>
```

and remeber this

```
template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml"
```

it is location for your html view on app\design\frontend[your project]\default\template

Answer (score 0):

you can check your app\design\frontend[your project]\default\layout\catalog.xml & Find this line.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
        </block>
```

under this line. Add this code

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.sizes" as="sizes" template="catalog/product/view/sizes.phtml">
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Store Locator</value></action>
```

And create your own size.phtml file & save catalog/product/view/sizes.phtml & add this code.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct();
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('store_locator');
if ( is_object($attribute) ) {
$identifier = $_product->getData("store_locator");
}?>
<?php if ($_sizeBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($identifier)): ?>
<div class="std">
    <?php echo $_sizeBlock->toHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

clear cache & Reload your browser Now See finally your own tab But your code is not see yet becoz you need to create attribute & which  static block want to see put identifier name in attribute.

Answer (score -3):

Adding your custom tab to `magento` is not very difficult need to play with attributes, block and phtml you can get a brief description

[here](http://www.ddcantt.in/2015/06/how-to-add-custom-additional-tab-for-my.html)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Links to resources are helpful, but please include the reasons why it helps and any example code in your answer. If the link dies, you are likely to have this downvoted or deleted due to the answer becoming redundant.

Comment: The link did die eventually!